# Error while deploying from Gitlab to ECS using ecs-cli

Tags: amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, gitlab, amazon-ecs

I am getting the below error while I am trying to stand-up containers in ECS from a pipeline in Gitlab. When I attempt to do it from my my local machine, it succeeds with no issues. The following is the error from the job on the runner.

```shell
level=error msg="Failed to Create Cluster" error="NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors"
time="2018-03-22T19:50:34Z" level=fatal msg="Error executing 'up': NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors"
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The ECS profile and configuration were both successfully generated prior to `esc-cli up` being called.

Also, below is the script from the gitlab-ci.yml.

```yaml
- ecs-cli configure profile --profile-name $AWS_PROFILE --access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- ecs-cli configure --cluster $AWS_CLUSTER --default-launch-type EC2 --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --config-name $AWS_CONFIGURATION
- ecs-cli up --keypair $AWS_KEY_PAIR --capability-iam --size 2 --instance-type t2.medium --vpc $AWS_VPC --subnets $AWS_SUBNETS --force
- ecs-cli compose -f docker-compose.ecs.yml service up
```

**Update:**
Seems that the issue is not the Gitlab Runner but the Docker container that the runner is executing the commands in. I recreated this locally, by running the same commands out of a Docker container.

```docker
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7

ENV AWS_KEY_PAIR=my-aws-key-pair
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my-aws-access-key-id
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my-aws-secret-access-key
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
ENV AWS_PROFILE=gitlab-ci
ENV AWS_CONFIGURATION=my-configuration
ENV AWS_VPC=vpc-77d05d0c
ENV AWS_SUBNETS=subnet-43938527,subnet-7ab78755

RUN apk add --update curl \
  && curl -o /usr/local/bin/ecs-cli https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-ecs-cli/ecs-cli-linux-amd64-latest \
  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ecs-cli

RUN sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward \
  && ecs-cli configure profile --profile-name $AWS_PROFILE --access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
  && ecs-cli configure --cluster my-cluster --default-launch-type EC2 --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --config-name $AWS_CONFIGURATION \
  && ecs-cli up --keypair $AWS_KEY_PAIR --instance-role gitlab-ci-role --size 1 --instance-type t2.medium --vpc $AWS_VPC --subnets $AWS_SUBNETS --force \
  && ecs-cli compose -f docker-compose.ecs.yml service up
```

Comment: Sounds like something related to permissions (maybe check your IAM settings). Similar questions in this thread: https://github.com/apex/apex/issues/426

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is the case. Using the same exact config and credentials, it works completely on my local machine. Its only occurring when the Gitlab Runner is executing those commands.

Comment: When you're deploying via Gitlab, is it using any type of different user to issue that deployment?

Comment: The instance you're bringing up with Gitlab, does it have an IAM instance profile associated with it? Another related thread: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/105 -- the reason I keep asking about IAM is (apart from these threads) is that my team just ran into a similar error this week, and the solution was adding the IAM instance profile to the hosts (we did it in our launch config, but I assume you can do it via other means).

Comment: I'm currently using the Gitlab credentials and config on my local to bring up the ECS resources. Everything works locally, but as soon as the pipeline tries to do it, it fails. Yeh, the EC2 instances all have a IAM role associated to them.